# How to load a script based on a class found within the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use JavaScript or jQuery to load/link a script based on an HTML class found on the page?

I downloaded a script that places a class in the HTML when desktop/mobile/tablet is detected and would like to load a js file based on one of those for desktop users.

```
<html lang="en" class="desktop">
<html lang="en" class="tablet">
<html lang="en" class="mobile">
```

So what I want is to link/load a js file when the "desktop" class is assigned

if .desktop , then load ......../thisfile.js

Sorry for being clueless on this, I did a search and couldn't find an answer I understood how to implement.

Comment: What's the name of the script that add the class? Did you check if there's the chance to give it a function to be run once it recognizes the client type?

Comment: Here is the site where i got the script https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js  , i created a test on my server , but i used the css method , as i'm clueless with jquery/java - i tested the css on ipad/iphone/android/surface/pc/laptop and its all good for my purposes - here is my demo http://nitrografixx.com/menu/test.html  , i have searched for weeks for a solution to hide/show some div depending on mobile/tablet/desktop and this one worked the best for me (at least from the suggestions i could understand lol)

Comment: What script is adding the class? Seems like not the best approach. Things like Modernizr can be used for feature detection, and CSS can be used for resolution-specific layouts. I'm just wondering where your script determines a mobile (phone?) ends and tablet begins. Have you seen the Note 3? It's huge.

Comment: thanks Mike i will take a look , as i said i'm a graphics guy and can work my way through html and css as i need to style for appearances. But i have a nice hover menu that works fine on every device i tested aside from that stupid MS Surface , and the above js was the only file i could find that specifically would target that device, so i used it. I tried media queries , but they were effecting the ipad as well

Comment: Wait a moment, if you're changing the HTML tag, why don't you just change the JS include, or is something else changing that tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is this

```
if ($('html').is('.desktop')){
    $.getScript('url_of_js_file.js');
}
// You could also use .hasClass('desktop')
```

But to avoid an if/else jungle if you call your JS files `desktop.js`, `tablet.js`, etc you could do this.

```
var htmlclass=$('html').prop('class');
$.getScript(htmlclass + '.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery function `jQuery.getScript()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

So you'd do something like:

```
if($(".classname")[0]) {
    //call getScript
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use only one class and modify the class using css media queries. Look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) for examples of how this can be done. In my opinion it will simplify things.